# Permutation of nested lists in Python

Tags: python, text, permutation, python-itertools, combinatorics

Imagine a list of lists, like this:

`x=[['foo','bar'],['baz'],['xyz']]`

Except longer. I need a script to generate permutations for a list of arbitrary length containing small sets of words, also of arbitrary length.

So, in this case:

```
[['foo','bar'],['baz'],['xyz']]
[['foo','bar'],['xyz'],['baz']]
[['xyz'],['baz'],['foo','bar']]
[['baz'],['xyz'],['foo','bar']]
[['xyz'],['foo','bar'],['baz']]
[['baz'],['foo','bar'],['xyz']]
```

I've not been able to manage this with itertools. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a direct function in itertools. What have you done so far? Where are you stuck? Please include your try in the question, so we can help you correct it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! `itertools.permutations(x)`! (although your ordering requirement is rather unusual/inconsistent... not sure if that matters)

Answer (score 0):

Try `permutations()` from itertools:

```
from itertools import permutations
x=[['foo','bar'],['baz'],['xyz']]
for y in permutations(x):
  print(y)
```